# child.expect fails with: "isalive() encountered condition where "terminated" is 0, but there was no child process. "

Tags: python, pexpect

I am using pexpect to spawn "svn" and run different commands.
It was working fine on my CentOS 5.9. When we ran the same code on a virtual machine under virtualBox running same version of CentOS it gives us following error from time to time:

"ExceptionPexpect: isalive() encountered condition where "terminated" is 0, but there was no child process. Did someone else call waitpid() on our process?"

At some times it comes up at child.close() and sometimes immediately after spawn when i call child.expect.

Looking at pexpect.py code , the comment says this condition should never occur.
I am totally confused why is this happening, i am not 100% sure if it is only happening because we are running on a virtual machine or it shows up there because of some other reason.

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Any reason not to use one of the Python subversion wrappers (either the one that comes bundled with svn, or `pysvn`) instead of trying to `pexpect` the CLI tool?

Comment: For that matter, even if you want to drive the CLI, why do you need `pexpect` for that? The only inputs `svn` should ever expect are Y/N prompts that are easier to handle by passing flags than by trying to automate answering them.